# I need to execute my python code on raspberry pi 4 automatically, in Every per minute

Tags: command-line, cron, raspberrypi, python-2.7

I entered this command to execute:

```
* * * * * python/home/pi/Desktop/sensor.py >> /var/log/gasdetails.log 2>&1
```

but it gives an info:

Dec 22 21:08:01 raspberrypi CRON[2070]: (CRON) info (No MTA installed, discarding output)

[image]

Comment: If you're trying to execute the **command** `python` with the name of your program as its **argument** then you need to separate them with whitespace ex. `python /home/pi/Desktop/sensor.py`

Comment: The error you are seeing is not related to your script, but to the fact that no Mail Transfer Agent (MTA) is installed in your system.

Comment: You can also implement the timer into the python script. I found this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34589347/run-python-script-every-10-seconds/34589422) on stackoverflow.

Answer (score 2):

As I understand it, this message informs you that your cron job **has** been executed, but output produced by it cannot be mailed to you because there is no Mail Transfer Agent installed on this machine.

I only wonder what output could it produce if you redirected everything to file. As one of the comments suggests, it may be an error message related to the fact that you probably don't have a file `python/home/pi/Desktop/sensor.py` on your system, so it cannot be executed. If you want to have the file `/home/pi/Desktop/sensor.py` executed by `python` interpreter (which is probably what you meant), you should write it as `python /home/pi/Desktop/sensor.py` (note the space).

Or do it "the proper Linux way" ;) - insert `#!/usr/bin/python` as the first line of your script, make the file executable and call it just as `/home/pi/Desktop/sensor.py`